# adb restore not working for shared

Tags: adb, nexus-4, encryption, restore, titanium-backup

I have a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.1 … I've read that we [could root it without wiping the data](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46366874&postcount=35) …  well didn't work for me!

I wasn't scared, because I made a full backup using:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all --nosystem
```

Two things I forgot

- SMS are not restored
- Google Authenticator data are not restored (the
  same week I switch all my accounts to two-step auth, like MtGOX …)

However, the problem is this :

Almost everything is restored, except the Pictures ..

Here is a part of the logs from log cat during the restore process

```
 adb shell logcat

I/BackupManagerService(  605): File in shared storage: 0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130731_170638.jpg
D/BackupManagerService(  605): [discarding file content]
I/BackupManagerService(  605): File in shared storage: 0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130731_170235.jpg
D/BackupManagerService(  605): [discarding file content]
I/BackupManagerService(  605): File in shared storage: 0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130731_170116.jpg
D/BackupManagerService(  605): [discarding file content]
I/BackupManagerService(  605): File in shared storage: 0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130731_170110.jpg
```

My question is, how to restore the pictures ?
There is no "adb restore -shared" option ..

In addition, it seem that all the android backup extractor solutions abe, perl, and the last version Titanium Pro, are not able to open encrypted android 4.4 backups …

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

Got a reply from Android Backup Developer (abe.jar) and this change + recompilation fixed the problem of extracting the backup. But this is not answering my initial question, why the photos are not restored using adb restore.

Full discussion here: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/issues/7

> This is the result of the change described here:
>   http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2013/12/changes-to-secretkeyfactory-api-in.html
>
> and can be probably treated as an Android bug, because restring
>   backups made with 4.3 will most likely fail on 4.4. File one at
>   b.android.com if you can confirm this.
>
> The fix is to replace
>   PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToBytes(pwArray) in
>   AndroidBackup.java:413 with
>   PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(pwArray). There
>   probably needs to be some flag to switch behaviour for 4.4 and prior
>   versions.

Comment: I was just about recommending those "backup extractors". Have you been able to use them before (so it's something changed with Android 4.4 causing the trouble)? They should be able to work with encrypted backups in general.

Comment: I tried backupdecrypt.pl abe.jar and Titanium Backup PRO, they all failed like I have the wrong password. But with either perl or abe, the messages are different (verbiage) when I put the wrong password.  Keep in mind that the restore is working (except pictures), so my password is right :)

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. My point was rather if there were changes concerning encryption, introduced with 4.4 (if you have a <4.4 encrypted backup to verify), so it's not a generic encryption problem, but one specific to 4.4+.

Comment: Sorry about that then. I don't have any adb backups from before 4.4.1

Comment: NP. Maybe somebody else has a possibilty to check? Or even better: A solution?

Comment: just added an update from android backup extractor developer